# When would an XLOCK in a "nested transaction" be released?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions, locking, scope

In SQL Server 2008, I know there is no such thing as nested transactions. These only appear to exist. I also know that some experts **strongly** implore developers not to use the available pseudo nested transactions. For example, [here](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/A-SQL-Server-DBA-myth-a-day-%282630%29-nested-transactions-are-real.aspx).

However, I have a case where I need to take an XLOCK on a row in a particular nested procedure, but only for the duration of that procedure. It has to be that lock and I obviously want to drop the lock ASAP. In pseudo code:

```
...outer procedure
BEGIN TRAN Inner
EXEC InnerProcedure

    ...InnerProcedure...
    BEGIN TRAN Inner
    SELECT ... WITH (XLOCK, ROWLOCK)
    COMMIT TRAN Inner
    -- NEVER rollback here; get the outer procedure to do this
    ...End InnerProcedure...

COMMIT TRAN Outer
```

My questions are:

1. Is this a best practices pattern considering that SQL Server does not truly nest transactions?
2. Will the XLOCK be released at COMMIT TRAN Inner, or only at COMMIT TRAN Outer? I assume the answer is yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No. Do not use 'nested' transactions (even in TSQL). At best, they won't work as you think: [A SQL Server DBA myth a day: (26/30) nested transactions are real (False)](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/A-SQL-Server-DBA-myth-a-day-%282630%29-nested-transactions-are-real.aspx)
2. The XLOCK will be released at the outer transaction scope. [Updated: to include Remus's advice]

Comment: That's the article I referenced - it spells out the consequences clearly. However, the problem seems to only be on rollback, which I know how to handle. Keeping that lock for so long seems non-ideal.

Comment: All X locks are hold until the outermost transaction commits. Not doing so would allow a reader to read uncommitted changes, since the outermost transaction can always rollback *after* the inner transaction has committed.

Comment: @IanC: ah, sorry Ian I missed that. Believe it or not I was reading that series of posts just 2 days ago!

Comment: @Remus I went and did some tests and you are spot on. Pls. post as answer so I can accept. BOL doesn't exactly spell this out. I assume the same would be true of UPDLOCK.